# listing entries on lowest category level only

Tags: categories

I'm using a classic /products/category/subcategory/ url structure.

On parent category pages I'm displaying a list of subcategories. However, for categories without children I'd like to show entries in stead.

Any thoughts on how to best approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a plugin from GWcode that detects if subcategories exist via url segments: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-haschildren